# Characteristic functions are not in $H^{1/2}$.

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

This is an exercise from Lieb, Loss.
I need to show that no characteristic function of a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with a finite positive measure is in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or even in $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I know that that the distributional partial derivatives of such a function must be zero.

But I don't see the contradiction since in that case the derivatives are in ${\rm L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I would also like some help with the second part. According to the book, a function is in $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+2\pi|k|)|\hat{f}(k)|^2{\rm d}k$ is finite. But for an arbitrary $A$, how can I know enough about $\chi_A$ to show that this integral isn't finite?

Comment: Hint: the _distributional_ derivative of the characteristic function of (non-empty) interval $[a,b]$ is $\delta_a-\delta_b$, and those deltas are not in $L^2$...

Comment: I guess this is where I went wrong. I can see that in $\mathbb{R}$, and I'll try to convince myself that the distributional derivative of $\chi_A$ is like a "delta" on the boundary. Hope it works :)

Comment: So thank you very much!

Comment: Ran Kiri: you're welcome. Glad to help. :)

Comment: In higher dimension, instead of trying to use the precise form of a delta like distribution, to get that $f$ is not in $H^1$, it is sufficient to say that the gradient is $0$ almost everywhere, but of course not $0$ in the distribution sense. If it was an $L^2$ function, then it would imply that it is $0$ also in the sense of distribution, which is false.

Comment: There is another integral version of the $H^{1/2}$ seminorm that does not use the Fourier transform. I think it might be easier to prove the second assertion with it.